# \file_add_path:nN function appears to have gone overboard

Tags: expl3

The `l3ﬁle package` in the `interface3` document used to define the `\file_add_path:nN` function; but no longer. Has that function been discarded? If so I wonder how to work around this as I am using `\file_add_path` in some of my work.

Comment: The function is listed as deprecated in [`l3obsolete.txt`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/979341afa4e3a2cea64ff1e4fdadb966c1c8d5cc/l3kernel/l3obsolete.txt#L47) and is marked for removal at the end of 2018. The current definition can be found in [`l3file.dtx`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/78f12e5e63a24b1c7620ae7d7a75b82003154567/l3kernel/l3file.dtx#L2394-L2405).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file-handling functions were revised in July 2017: the commit that is most relevant is https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/bf52c87f72ba11c4309fb001321d708dda828239. The release announcement for the changes is https://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1707&L=LATEX-L&F=&S=&P=71: this one perhaps is a bit terse on the nature of the revisions. It is though listed in the [list of removed functions](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/l3obsolete.txt). The recommended replacement is `\file_get_full_name:nN`.

One can get information on deprecated functions and check for other issues by using

```
\RequirePackage[enable-debug ,check-declarations]{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\debug_on:n { deprecation }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

before loading a package to be checked.

Since the beginning of 2018, we have started a [detailed ChangeLog](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/CHANGELOG.md): all deprecations now get listed there.

Comment: the `detailed ChangeLog:` answers a question that I have meant to ask for quite a while. Thanks.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth If necessary, I can work back through to extend the log ...